# EGL_EXT_Compositor example and behavior

Tags: egl, opengl-sc

I’m trying to understand the usage of the [`EXT_compositor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/extensions/EXT/EGL_EXT_compositor.txt) extension.

The easiest way after reading the description of the extension is to see some usage example.
But no luck, I didn’t find any example at all.
So, does anyone have and can please upload some usage sample code?
And my main question regarding the extension:
what is the policy of overlapping windows? Is it just the windows order at attributes list or there’s a blend option between the windows?

Answer (score 0):

The extension does not provide any idea of overlapping windows. It simply provides a producing application the ability to render to an EGLSurface object. It then provides the Compositing application the ability to read that RGBA buffer as a texture object to OpenGL. The Compositing application can then layer the textures in any way it wants.